# Change of Steepness, how to do

Tags: math, xna

How would you go about changing the steepness as for loops progress. Essentially I've made a terrain with vertices which form a valley. The creation of the data for these vertices to use is here:

```
    // Divides it to a sensible height
    const int DIVISOR_NUMBER = 40;

    for (int x = 0; x < TerrainWidth; x++)
    {
        float height = Math.Abs(((float)x - ((float)TerrainWidth / 2))/ (float)DIVISOR_NUMBER);

        for (int y = 0; y < TerrainHeight; y++)
        {
            float copyOfHeight = height;
            float randomValue = random.Next(0, 3);
            copyOfHeight += randomValue / 10;
            HeightData[x, y] = copyOfHeight;
        }
    }
```

This works fine. But I now want to make the sides of the valley steeper at the start and end of the first loop and the valley flatten the closer to the center it gets. I'm having a bit of a mental block and can't think of a good way of doing it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a squared (aka quadratic) curve for that.  Try:

```
float offset = (float)x - (float)TerrainWidth/2;
float height = offset*offset*SCALE_FACTOR;
```

If you still want a "crease" at the bottom of the valley, you can make your height a weighted sum:

```
float height = Math.Abs(offset) * ABS_FACTOR + offset*offset * QUADRATIC_FACTOR;
```

Comment: I'm guessing cubing this affect would make it even more pronounced?

Comment: Cubing would make the valley flatter and the curve up at the edge more sudden.  You would also need to use `Math.Abs()` to deal with negative offsets.